# Style ng2-bootstrap's typeahead list-items

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-typeahead, ng2-bootstrap

Problem:

[image: ng2-boostrap typeahead transparent background]

I want the results to be below each other (full width) and not to have a transparent background. I right clicked one of the items and clicked 'inspect' so I figured out what to use as a selector.

**What I have tried:**

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
background-color: black !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
color: yellow !important;
```

}

Didn't change a thing, so either I'm not selecting it right or I don't know. I have a custom template:

```
<template #customItemTemplate let-model="item" let-index="index">
    <h5 style="width: 100%">{{model.title || model.name}}</h5>
</template>
```

but even in-line style didn't change a thing.

**Question:**

How can I style the results?

**PS:**
I figured it might be useful to mention that I'm using MaterializeCSS.

Comment: did you get this working with optionslist template

Comment: @KaranGarg If I remember correctly, I stopped trying and used something else. But I did start an [issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1557) back then on the author's GitHub page, maybe that can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I have exposed `optionsListTemplate` input for `TypeaheadDirective` in v1.3.1
so you can COMPLETELY override typeahead results template ;)
source code of default you can check here:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/src/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ts#L22-L32

Comment: I'm unable to call isActive or selectActive :(